# Oracle Contains Query Returning False Positives

Tags: oracle, contains

I am trying to search for names in a clob field in oracle using contains. I know the text I am testing this on contains 'Joe Smith' with one space in between Joe and Smith, so this query works returns the records when I run it:

```
SELECT *
FROM case_search
WHERE contains(text, 'Joe Smith', 1) > 0
```

The issue is that this query, with two spaces between Joe and Smith, is also returning the text as a hit but the text only has 'Joe Smith' with one space and not 'Joe  Smith' with two spaces:

```
SELECT *
FROM case_search
WHERE contains(text, 'Joe  Smith', 1) > 0
```

I can add as many spaces as I would like in between Joe and Smith and it still returns a hit. I need to add the name that hit in the exact form to another table in order for something to work later. Can anyone explain what is happening here and how to fix it?

Comment: Search words that don't have a specific operator between them are presumed to have an implied `AND`, so no matter how many spaces you put between `Joe` and `Smith`, `Contains()` will always interpret it as `Joe AND Smith`. Most DBMSs accept double quotes as delimiters within `Contains` phrases, so you might try `Contains(text, '"Joe Smith"', 1) > 0` (with one space between them).